# перебор всех комбинаций (перестановка) с учетом дополнительного воздействия функцией на элемент списка

Tags: python, комбинаторика

Допустим, есть список из n=2 элементов [A,B], состоящий из чисел А,В, и есть входная функция, которая меняет знак у числа А.(поскольку в данном случае функция представляет собой мультипликатор и имеет всего два выходных параметра [1,-1], то m=2). В общем случае функция может иметь м выходных параметров) Необходимо получить на выходе список вида:
[[A,B],[-A,B],[A,-B],[-A,-B],[B,A],[-B,A],[B,-A],[-B,-A]]
Общее число вариантов, если я правильно прикинул: n!*(m^n)
начало я написал, просто перебор:

```
import itertools
sp = ['A', 'B']
s1 = list(itertools.permutations(sp, len(sp)))
print(s1)
```

потом есть идея применить битовую маску из двузначного представления числа n и перемножить полученные два списка, но вот реализовать пока не могу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`combinations` принимает функцию `f` и набор элементов `seq`. `f` по аргументу  `x` возвращает список значений. В примере это будут `-x` и `x`.

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) комбинирует варианты. [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) перемешивает каждый вариант.

Список лучше не строить. В комбинаторике списки быстро перестают помещаться в память, а перебор работает и памяти много не требует.

```
import itertools


def combinations(f, seq):
    for p in itertools.product(*map(f, seq)):
        yield from itertools.permutations(p)


def f(x):
    return -x, x


for c in combinations(f, (1, 2)):
    print(*c)
```

> ```
> -1 -2
> -2 -1
> -1 2
> 2 -1
> 1 -2
> -2 1
> 1 2
> 2 1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
sp = [7, -2]         # например

a, b = sp            # отделим его элементы и создаем из них 2 кортежи (или списки)
x = (a, -a)
y = (b, -b)

s1 = [[i, j] for i in x for j in y] \
   + [[j, i] for i in x for j in y]

print(s1)
```

*Вывод:*

> ```
> [[7, -2], [7, 2], [-7, -2], [-7, 2], [-2, 7], [2, 7], [-2, -7], [2, -7]]
> ```

Comment: Сработает ли ваш метод для n=3 или большего?

Comment: @MBo, не сработает, конечно. То вы хотите, чтобы работал, а не вопрошатель ;-) — по крайней мере, он об этом не упомянул. ;-)

Comment: Полагаю, что пример с n=2 приведён из-за небольшого размера, тем более, что далее упоминается количество  n!*(2^m)  (не совсем верное)

Comment: Спасибо, @MBo. Действительно, в формуле допустил ошибку. Правильный вариант n!*(m^n). Подправлю условие.